# How is this "referenced before assignment"?

Tags: python

I have a bit of Python to connect to a database with a switch throw in for local versus live.

```
    LOCAL_CONNECTION = {"server": "127.0.0.1", "user": "root", "password": "", "database": "testing"}
    LIVE_CONNECTION = {"server": "10.1.1.1", "user": "x", "password": "y", "database": "nottesting"}

    if debug_mode:
        connection_info = LOCAL_CONNECTION
    else:
        connnection_info = LIVE_CONNECTION
    self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = connection_info["server"], user = connection_info["user"], passwd = connection_info["password"], db = connection_info["database"])
```

Works fine locally (Windows, Python 2.5) but live (Linux, Python 2.4) I'm getting:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connection_info' referenced before assignment
```

I see the same error even if I remove the if/ else and just assign connection info directly to the LIVE_CONNECTION value. If I hard-code the live connection values into the last line, it all works. Clearly I'm sleepy. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The second assignement is misspelled.

You wrote `connnection_info = LIVE_CONNECTION` with 3 n's.

Comment: Yep! Even when I saw the '=' didn't line up it took a third scan for me to find the extra n.  Anyway, hopefully Tom's next question isn't about static typing :)

Comment: Wow, I am a yutz. You'd think the whitespace of Python would have made it obvious to me when that = didn't line up. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Typo: connnection_info = LIVE_CONNECTION