# Another local variable referenced before assignment - Python

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7

I'll start by saying: 
I know this is a question that gets asked a lot.  I've read the other answers, and have ruled out:

I'm not using += for the assignment;

I've tried explicitly assigning each variable within the function to ensure they're not empty, in case the other work the function does fails;

They're **not** global variables, and I don't want them to be - they're just internal variables that I use to work out what I'm eventually returning.

```
    ##  Gets the data from external website - refreshes whenever the programme is called. 
## Urllib2 required module 
##  csv to make life easier handling the data 

import urllib2
import csv
import sys  
import math
# import sqlite3    #don't need this just now, will probably run Django with MySQL when it comes to it
# import MySQLdb Likewise, don't need this just now. 
#python3
import atexit
from time import time
from datetime import timedelta

def secondsToStr(t):
    return str(timedelta(seconds=t))

line = "="*40
def log(s, elapsed=None):
    print(line)
    print(secondsToStr(time()), '-', s)
    if elapsed:
        print("Elapsed time:", elapsed)
    print(line)
    print()

def endlog():
    end = time()
    elapsed = end-start
    log("End Program", secondsToStr(elapsed))

def now():
    return secondsToStr(time())

start = time()
atexit.register(endlog)
log("Start Program")
def open_external_source():
    # Checks if the core file's been modified since the last time we used it - if it hasn't, then we skip all of the file reading stuff. 
    #need to change this to just pull the headers the first time.  
    master_data_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1213/E0.csv", "GET")
    print master_data_file
    headers = master_data_file.info()
    last_mod = headers["last-modified"]
    settings = open ("settings.csv","r+")
    historic_last_mod = settings.readline() #this only works when the setting is a 1 line file
    print "Local file version: " + historic_last_mod 
    print "Server file version: " +last_mod
    if last_mod == historic_last_mod :
        print "It's the same, file not loaded"
        return true
    else : 
        return false
    settings.close()

#the if statement's commented out because it was messing up the variables into the function
#if open_external_source == False:
master_data_file = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1213/E0.csv", "GET")
data = list(tuple(rec) for rec in csv.reader(master_data_file, delimiter=','))
print len(data)
print "printing full file"
print data
league_list = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", "Newcastle", "Norwich","Reading","Southampton", "Stoke", "Sunderland", "Swansea", "Tottenham", "West Brom", "West Ham", "Wigan"]

league_stats = league_list

#for teams in league_list: - come back to this, will do this as a split and append. 


#call the next set of functions to skip the data reading stuff 
#This is the data reading section, that puts the data into our system
#If we do proceed, then we redo all of the calculations, and read the data file in again, in case of any corrections, etc.  

#Column references:
#Home Goals 4
#Away Goals 5
#Full Time Result 6
#Home Shots 10
#Away Shots 11
#Home Shots on Target 12
#Away Shots on Target 13


#Calculates the average for a given team at home, columns are 4 Home Goals, 5 Away Goa
def CalcAverageHome(team, column, data):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    n=0
    for row in data:
        if  data[count][2] == team:
            total += int(data[count][column])
            n+=1
        count += 1      
    try:
        average = float(total) / n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        average = 'Not played'
    return average

def CalcAverageAway(team, column, data):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    n=0
    for row in data:
        if  data[count][3] == team:
            total += int(data[count][column])
            n+=1
        count += 1      
    try:
        average = float(total) / n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        average = 'Not played'  
    return average


home_team = "Chelsea"
away_team = "Newcastle" 
print "Here's the Average number of goals scored Home"
home_goals = CalcAverageHome(home_team, 4, data)
away_goals = CalcAverageAway(home_team, 5, data)
home_conceded = CalcAverageHome(home_team, 5, data) 
away_conceded = CalcAverageAway(away_team, 4, data)
adjusted_home = home_goals * away_conceded
adjusted_away = away_goals * home_conceded

print home_team, home_goals, home_conceded, adjusted_home
print away_team, away_goals, away_conceded, adjusted_away

print "starting to try and work the league averages out here." 

def poisson_probability(actual, mean):
    # naive:   math.exp(-mean) * mean**actual / factorial(actual)

    # iterative, to keep the components from getting too large or small:
    p = math.exp(-mean)
    for i in xrange(actual):
        p *= mean
        p /= i+1
    return p

for i in range (10):
    print str((100*poisson_probability(i,adjusted_home)))+"%"


league_list = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", "Newcastle", "Norwich","Reading","Southampton", "Stoke", "Sunderland", "Swansea", "Tottenham", "West Brom", "West Ham", "Wigan"]


# just assign the league list to the stats for now - 
# eventually each team entry will become the first column of a new sublist

def LeagueAverages(data,column):
    total = 0
    n = 0
    for row in data :
        string = row[column]
        if string.isdigit() == True:
            total = total + int(row[column])
            n += 1
    league_average = float(total) / n
    return league_average


print "League home goals average is:", LeagueAverages(data, 4)
print "League away goals average is:", LeagueAverages(data, 5)

print "finished that loop..."




league_stats = []
test_team = "Arsenal"

# Function iterates through the league teams and calculates the averages
# and places them in one long list. 
for team in league_list:
    league_stats.append(team)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 4, data))
    print CalcAverageHome(team, 4, data)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 5, data))
    CalcAverageHome(team, 5, data)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 7, data))
    CalcAverageHome(team, 7, data)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 8, data))
    CalcAverageHome(team, 8, data)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 10, data))
    CalcAverageHome(team, 10, data)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 11, data))
    CalcAverageHome(team, 11, data)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 12, data))
    CalcAverageHome(team, 12, data)
    league_stats.append(CalcAverageHome(team, 13, data))
    CalcAverageHome(team, 13, data)

# This function should chunk the 'file', as when we run the above code, 
# we'll end up with one incredibly long list that contains every team on the same line
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))

chunker (league_stats, 9)

final_stats = []
for group in chunker(league_stats, 9):
   print repr(group)
   final_stats.append(repr(group))

#retrieve a particular value from the final stats array
"""
    for row in final_stats:
        if  data[count][2] == team:
            total += int(data[count][column])
            n+=1
        count += 1  
"""

def create_probability_table(hometeam, awayteam, final_stats):
#reads in the home and away sides, calculates their performance adjusted 
#ratings and then calculates the likelihood of each team scoring a particular
#number of goals (from 0-10)
#those likelihoods are then combined to provide an 11x11 matrix of probabilities
    poisson_array = []
    poisson_list_home = []
    poisson_list_away = []
    goals_home = 0
    conceded_home = 0
    goals_away = 0
    conceded_away = 0

    for team in final_stats:
        if team == hometeam:
            goals_home = team[1]
            conceded_home = team [3]
            print "home Goals, Home Conceded"
            print goals_home, conceded_home
        elif team == awayteam:
            goals_away = team[2]
            conceded_away = team[4]
            print "Away Goals, Away Conceded"
            print goals_away, conceded_away, 
        else:           
            pass

    adjusted_goals_home = goals_home * conceded_away
    adjusted_goals_away = goals_away * conceded_home 

    #this section creates the two probability lists for home and away num goals scored      
    for i in range (10):

        poisson_list_home.append = (100*poisson_probability(i,adjusted_goals_home))
        poisson_list_away.append = (100*poisson_probability(i,adjusted_goals_away))

    print poisson_list_home
    print poisson_list_away

    for number in poisson_list_home:
        for number in poisson_list_away:
            probability_table.append(poisson_list_home[number] * poisson_list_away[number])
    return probability_table 

create_probability_table("Arsenal", "Chelsea", final_stats)

#and this section cross multiplies them into a new list

#   for i in range (10):

# print data_frame [0:100] prints to console to provide visual check

master_data_file.close()
```

When I run it, it throws a

```
line 272, in create_probability_table
adjusted_goals_home = goals_home * conceded_away UnboundLocalError: local variable 'conceded_away' referenced before assignment
```

error - I don't understand why!  It is defined and assigned - right at the start of the function.  It's not global.

I've looked at these questions, and they don't seem to answer the question:
[Local (?) variable referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904981/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment)
[Assigning to variable from parent function: "Local variable referenced before assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934772/local-var-referenced-before-assignment)
[How is this "referenced before assignment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754421/how-is-this-referenced-before-assignment)
[UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Core_prices' referenced before assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950576/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-core-prices-referenced-before-assignment)

Comment: at the first `if` in your `for`, your indentation is off

Comment: What is the error you're getting? It would help to know which variable is being referenced before assignment. Anyway, you might have a problem with indentation - the `elif` is aligned with the `for` instead of with the `if`, and the line after `if team == hometeam` is misaligned.

Comment: what line is the error on, can we see the traceback?

Comment: you also wrote con **d** eded_away = 0

Comment: The indentation is fine in the original code, it's been my crappy copy and pasting.  Hang on and I'll adjust it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled "conceded":

```
condeded_away = 0
   ^
```

Also, you may want to use a different data structure for `final_stats`, like a dictionary:

```
teams = {
    'team1': [...],
    'team2': [...],
    ...
}
```

You can then look up the stats for a team much more quickly:

```
stats = teams['team2']
```

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: `adjusted_goals_home` is local to your function, so it doesn't exist outside of its scope. You should either make it global or `return` it from `create_probability_table` and store it in another variable.

Comment: That's an unrelated error, right?  `adjusted_goals_home` isn't defined anywhere in this block of code... so it's a local.  If you're using it later (outside this function), that would result in the error.

Comment: @RobI: It's defined in the second-to-last line.

Comment: That's right - I want it to be local, where I'm assigning it is still supposed to be in the function.  I go on to run a nested loop using adjusted_goals_home and away before returning something else, but I hadn't included it as it's another 30 lines.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: So where is the traceback coming from, inside or outside of this function?

Comment: Still inside the function.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: Without the rest of your source code, it's not really possible to say much more.

Comment: Is there any easy way to put it in and preserve the indentation?  I don't have enough reputation to add a screenshot with the line numbers.  :(

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: Do you use tabs or something? Paste it in and press CTRL-K

Comment: Added that now, that's a really helpful shortcut!

Comment: @ChrisCampbell: Something's probably up with your indentation. Your code should work.

Comment: I've done some more debugging.  When I print out final_stats, it's showing me the list looks like this:
`"['Arsenal', 2.473684210526316, 1.2105263157894737,...`  - does that mean it's converted it all to strings?  Might explain why my multiplications doesn't work, but not why it's saying unassigned, given that it's explicitly assigned each variable to 0 at the start.