# List of lists chunked into sublists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of lists I'm using as a data container.  I've left all of my debugging code in, everything goes to console so I can follow it through, which explains some of the more redundant print statements.

It's created by iterating through and making one long list that looks like:

`[['Arsenal', 2.47, 1.2, 0.89, 'Chelsea', 2.15, 0.8, 1.21,...`

The sublists are all of uniform length (9 elements), so I used the following to chunk it, which is [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751478/1293222):

```
# This function should chunk the 'file', as when we run the above code, 
# we'll end up with one incredibly long list that contains every team on the same line
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))

for group in chunker(league_stats, 9):
   print repr(group)
   final_stats.append(repr(group))
   print "printing final stats"
   print final_stats
   print "and here's a line break"
```

It then should look like this:

`[['Arsenal', 2.47, 1.2, 0.89],
['Chelsea', 2.15, 0.8, 1.21]...]`

But if I print it it's showing as:

`["['Arsenal', 2.47, 1.2, 0.89]",
['Chelsea', 2.15, 0.8, 1.21|]..."]`

If i iterate through it, it seems to show as expected

So that seems to have made each entire sublist a string, rather than a list, is that right?  This has two weird knock ons - if I access elements using final_stats[0][2], for example, it gives me an 'A' instead of 'Arsenal', which I would expect.

The other, of course, is that I can't run logical operations against list elements - what's the best way to chunk the long list, or to stop this from happening?

If you need the full code (not included here for brevity), then it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328442/another-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-python)  - I suspect that this question was inadvertantly caused by the issue in this post.

Someone on that answer suggested using dictionaries as a better data container - I'm pretty happy with the list structure, and it feels (to me as a newbie) a bit simpler for what I want to do - these data structures are always uniform sizes, so I don't want to change the data types unless I **really** have to.  I think it's a helpful thing I'll look into long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) gets the representation of a string. i.e:

```
print repr("""Hello!
this is a test string
yay.""")
```

Returns:

```
'Hello!\nthis is a test string\nyay.'
```

In your code, it is converting a list to a string, and that is why when you do `[0][2]` you get a character and not something you would expect.

There's no need to call it in your code. Just append the chuncked list normally.

Comment: Muh.  So simple.  And just like that, two questions are answered.